# Implementation of SQL Data Export Service in c#

Tags: c#

I'm new to Azure, I want to know about how we can implement SQL Data Export Service in c#.

my actual problem is "I am using C#.net to implement some web services and also use SQL azure as database for that services. So there each day i want to check whether there is any updation in my database. If there is an updation then i want to read only that updated data from my sql azure database and load that datainto some another sql database(both SQL Server and SQL Azure)". So i want to implement this function as windows azure worker role. So each and every day these worker role be executed. How i can implement that entire operation using c#.net.
If anyone know the solution please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you will have to create a "Worker Role", which is similar to a window service.

For details have a look at
[How to create a worker role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh285885)
and also
[Building Windows Azure Service: Worker Role Background Tasks Handler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/morebits/archive/2011/01/01/building-windows-azure-service-part5-worker-role-background-tasks-handler.aspx)